# Modifying values in existing records using trigger

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following data

```
id INT
time_stamp timestamp
status INT
```

When inserting, the time_stamp attribute will always be current_timestamp, once the current timestamp is more than 48 hrs of the value inserted in the table, i need to change the status to 0.

I created the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER new_table_AINS 
BEFORE INSERT ON new_table
FOR EACH ROW begin
DECLARE now_value timestamp;
SET @now_value = current_timestamp;
UPDATE new_table SET new.status = 0 where @now_value = new.time_stamp + interval 48 hour;
END$$
```

But when I try to insert a new row, I get Error Code 1442 in MySQL

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'new_table' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger. Please help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's cause you are trying to triggering action on same table on which it's created. Recursive trigger is not allowed in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a "before" trigger, you cannot re-modify the table that you are triggering on.  However, I don't think you need a trigger.  Instead, use a view:

```
create view v_ new_table_AINS as
    select . . .,
           (case when current_timestamp >= time_stamp + interval 48 hour then 0
                 else status
            end)
    from new_table_AINS;
```

At your leisure, you can then run a job that updates the status to zero for old timestamps.